# Transaction gas cost in truffle test case

Tags: truffle, javascript, unittesting

Below is from a truffle test cases in javascript, where I was trying to add the gas cost to an account balance to confirm the sum of transaction, where the sum should be equal to the previous balance.

But I couldn't get it to work!

The rcpt.cumulativeGasUsed, web3.eth.gasPrice, getBalance(accounts[1]) are all correct, but the arithmetic is not, some fromWei, toWei kung-fu needed?

What am I doing wrong here?

```
            return instance.bailOut({ from: accounts[1] }).then(function (resp) {
            var rcpt = web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(resp.tx);
            console.log("Sum: " + ((rcpt.cumulativeGasUsed * web3.eth.gasPrice) + web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[1]).toString(10)));
```

});

After a lot of experiments, it looks like the below method works fine, but couldn't explain the logic of transaction cost! Any idea is most welcome.

Anyways unit test is passing now!!!

```
return contractInstance.withdraw({ value: web3.toWei(1, "ether"), gas: 1000000 }).then(function () {
          var contractAddressBalance = web3.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance(contractAddress).toString(10));
          console.log("contractAddress balance after withdraw: " + contractAddressBalance);
          return contractInstance.bailOut({ from: accounts[1] }).then(function (resp) {
            var rcpt = web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(resp.tx);

            console.log("cumulativeGasUsed: " + rcpt.cumulativeGasUsed);
            console.log("gasPrice: " + web3.eth.gasPrice);

            var transactionCost = (rcpt.cumulativeGasUsed / 10000000); // How come this works???

            console.log("transactionCost: " + transactionCost);
            console.log("Account[1] balance after withdraw: " + web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[1]));

            contractWalletAfter = web3.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[1]).add(web3.fromWei(rcpt.cumulativeGasUsed)));
            assert.equal(((contractWalletAfter.minus(contractWalletBefore)).add(transactionCost)).valueOf(), 6, "6 wasn't in the contract wallet");
          });
        });
```

Comment: The correct formula for the ether paid by a transaction should be `gasUsed * gasPrice + value`. If the contracts make a transfer to the sender that will change the final balance.

Comment: yup, that is what my understanding also. You can see that in my original question, where I did `rcpt.cumulativeGasUsed * web3.eth.gasPrice` to get the transaction cost. But it didn't work! If you have a console open, you can quickly verify the same with the Metacoin in a truffle test case. Looks like some truffle test magic???

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Note: This answer is only valid for Truffle v4.

---

I've tried this test with the MetaCoin example from truffle (ie run `truffle unbox metacoin` in an empty directory)

```
var MetaCoin = artifacts.require("./MetaCoin.sol");

contract('MetaCoin', function(accounts) {
  it("Test gas", async () => {
    const meta = await MetaCoin.deployed();

    // Initial balance of the second account
    const initial = await web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[1]);
    console.log(`Initial: ${initial.toString()}`);

    // Obtain gas used from the receipt
    const receipt = await meta.sendCoin(accounts[2], 1, { from: accounts[1] });
    const gasUsed = receipt.receipt.gasUsed;
    console.log(`GasUsed: ${receipt.receipt.gasUsed}`);

    // Obtain gasPrice from the transaction
    const tx = await web3.eth.getTransaction(receipt.tx);
    const gasPrice = tx.gasPrice;
    console.log(`GasPrice: ${tx.gasPrice}`);

    // Final balance
    const final = await web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[1]);
    console.log(`Final: ${final.toString()}`);
    assert.equal(final.add(gasPrice.mul(gasUsed)).toString(), initial.toString(), "Must be equal");
  });
});
```

The correspoding output is:

```
  Contract: MetaCoin
Initial: 99971803600000000000
GasUsed: 23497
GasPrice: 100000000000
Final: 99969453900000000000
    ✓ Test gas (199ms)

  1 passing (217ms)
```

One difference is that I'm reading the gasPrice from the transaction (`getTransaction(hash).gasPrice`) instead of the network `eth.gasPrice()`.

Comment: ok, that explains, `getTransaction(hash).gasPrice` is 100000000000 and  `eth.gasPrice()` is 20000000000 in my tests.

Comment: For me tx.gasPrice is not BN (string), tx.gasPrice is int -- both require: new BN( n );

Comment: @TheBurgerKing The answer from last year was for Truffle v4, that uses web3 v0.20 which uses a fork of BigNumber.js. Likely you are using the new Truffle v5, which uses web3 v1.0 which uses BN.js in turn. I'd suggest to create a new answer with the solution for Truffle v5. I'd edit my answer to indicate it was tested with Truffle v4.

Answer (score 4):

The following code is the same code as [Ismael](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/2124/ismael)'s code, with the changes to work with Truffle v5, as `getBalance`'s return type, beside `gasUsed` and `gasPrice` values are not BN by default:

```
var MetaCoin = artifacts.require("./MetaCoin.sol");

const { toBN } = web3.utils;

contract('MetaCoin', function(accounts) {
  it("Test gas", async () => {
    const meta = await MetaCoin.deployed();

    // Initial balance of the second account
    const initial = toBN(await web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[1]));
    console.log(`Initial: ${initial.toString()}`);

    // Obtain gas used from the receipt
    const receipt = await meta.sendCoin(accounts[2], 1, { from: accounts[1] });
    const gasUsed = toBN(receipt.receipt.gasUsed);
    console.log(`GasUsed: ${receipt.receipt.gasUsed}`);

    // Obtain gasPrice from the transaction
    const tx = await web3.eth.getTransaction(receipt.tx);
    const gasPrice = toBN(tx.gasPrice);
    console.log(`GasPrice: ${tx.gasPrice}`);

    // Final balance
    const final = toBN(await web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[1]));
    console.log(`Final: ${final.toString()}`);
    assert.equal(final.add(gasPrice.mul(gasUsed)).toString(), initial.toString(), "Must be equal");
  });
});
```